# dgrid with tree plugin not displaying the children when expanded

Tags: dgrid

When I expand a node in the tree of a grid, the ajax call is made to get the children but does not display children. Surely, something is wrong at the client side and I'm not sure, where I'm missing. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test JsonRest store</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=570">
    <style>
        @import "static/dojo-release-1.9.0/dojo/resources/dojo.css";    
        @import "static/dojo-release-1.9.0/dgrid/css/skins/claro.css";
        @import "static/dojo-release-1.9.0/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
        @import "static/dojo-release-1.9.0/dgrid/css/skins/tundra.css";

        h2 {
            margin: 12px;
        }
        .heading {
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-bottom: 0.25em;
        }
        .dgrid {
            margin: 10px;
        }


    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="'async':true,'parseOnLoad':true" src="static/dojo-release-1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>        
        require(["dgrid/List", "dgrid/OnDemandGrid","dgrid/Selection", "dgrid/editor", 
       "dgrid/Keyboard", "dgrid/Selection", "dgrid/tree", "dgrid/extensions/DnD",
       "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojox/json/ref", "dojo/store/Observable",
       "dojo/store/Cache", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/domReady!"], function(List, Grid, Selection, editor, Keyboard, Selection, tree, DnD, declare, JsonRest, jsonRef, Observable, Cache, Memory){

            var DnDList = declare([List, Keyboard, Selection, DnD]),
            DnDGrid = declare([Grid, Keyboard, Selection, DnD]);

            //dojox.json.ref.refAttribute = "uuid";
            var rootUuid = "ee9ac5d2-a07c-3981-a57a-f7f26baf38d8";

            var testStore = Cache(JsonRest({
            //Observable(Cache(JsonRest({
                target:"/uuid/",
                idProperty: "uuid",
                query: 

                function(query, options){                           
                    query = rootUuid+"/dojoTreeRoot";
                    options="";
                    return JsonRest.prototype.query.call(this, query, options);
                },                      
                getChildren : function(parent, options){                            
                    return testStore.get(parent.uuid).children;
                }               
            }), Memory());                                      

            var columns = [
                tree({label:'Name', field:'displayName', sortable: false})
            ];

            window.grid = new DnDGrid({ //new (declare([Grid, Selection, Keyboard]))({
                //sort: "id",
                store: testStore,
                selectionMode: "single",
                loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
                //noDataMessage: "No results found.",
                getBeforePut: false,
                columns: columns,                       
                dndParams: {
                    allowNested: true, // also pick up indirect children w/ dojoDndItem class
                    checkAcceptance: function(source, nodes) {
                        return source !== this; // Don't self-accept.
                    }
                }                   
            }, "grid");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <h2>A basic grid with JsonRest store</h2>
    <div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm going to wager a wild guess that `testStore.get(parent.uuid)` is not nearly guaranteed to return synchronously, but you are assuming it does.  Might be part of your problem.

Comment: Well, I see the http get request coming back successfully for testStore.get.

Comment: To add to my above comment, on page load, there is an ajax call that has both target & query (combined). Subsequent calls are made only while expanding a node. That too, they are not store.query but store.get. This implementations is slightly different form regular ones. This works perfectly in dijit.Tree, dojox.LazyTreeGrid. The reason I'm iomplementing in dgrid is to get both Dnd & performance for node with large children. Hope I explained well the background on this. Thanks for trying to help. I must have this working in order to start implementing other features.

Comment: Do any errors show up in the console?  If you add a breakpoint to your `getChildren` method does it get called?  My initial guess was based on figuring that since `JsonRest#get` returns a promise, not an immediate value, your code in `getChildren` would return `undefined`.  However, given that you're also using `Cache`, it may actually return synchronously since the parent would have to have been queried and put in the cache before that call.

Comment: No errors in console. getChildren gets called, no error there. But getChildren returns the "Json object" from the server not a "promise" and always returns "undefined".(but I noticed that as you said my first call to load the tree is a JsonRest#get which returns a promise). Or how should I implement the getChildren, what should it return, that's my big question now?              Is there a way to use $ref reference attribute with this store-jsonrest like in dijit/Tree or dojox/grid/LazyTreeGrid? I just need lazy loading and automatic call when a node is clicked/expanded.